# Como importar dados do DataGridView para textboxs

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Como eu faço para,quando eu clicar no botão modificar trazer os dados de  uma linha do DataGridView para os campos de cima e também se eu salvar como inativa deixar a linha como Enabled = false.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Web forms? Ou Windows

Comment: O tipo de formulário,né? se for é Windows Form.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtCodigo.text = dataGridView.Rows[indiceDaLinha].Cells["nomeDaCelula"].Value.toString();
```

Para o nome a mesma coisa.

Para os Radios vc faz:

```
if(dataGridView.Rows[inicideLinha].Cells["nomeDaCelula"].Value.toString().Equals("Inativa"))
{
    radioButtonInativa.checked = true;
}
```

Talvez você precise fazer algumas correções com relação ao nome dos seus componentes. Mas é assim que eu faria.